# Retained Core Foundation Property

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

(Xcode 4.2, iOS 5, **ARC**)

I have some properties of Core Foundation (/Graphics) objects that should take ownership of their objects. Now in these [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2) I found this:

> In OS X v10.6 and later, you can use the __attribute__ keyword to specify that a Core Foundation property should be treated like an
>   Objective-C object for memory management:
>   `@property(retain) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFDictionaryRef myDictionary;`

Unfortunately I couldn't find any elaboration on this. I'm using this:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CGImageRef loupeImage;`

And it seems to work the way I'd expect. It retains the object on setting the property and releases it when I set the property to nil.

Now my question is, do I still need to explicitly set those properties to nil in my dealloc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit:** My previous post was incorrect. `__attribute__((NSObject))` on the property only causes it to retain/release the property when using the property accessors. It does not affect access to the ivar, and notably, it does not nil out (or release) the property in `dealloc`. So yes, in your `dealloc` you either need to say `self.loupeImage = nil;` or you need to say `[_loupeImage release]`.

---

**Original post:**

If the compiler accepts the `strong` keyword, then it's going to treat it correctly, retaining and releasing as expected, and nilling out automatically in ARC. The whole idea of `__attribute__((NSObject))` is it tells the compiler to treat this object exactly as if it were an obj-c object, and so that's what it does.

So no, you shouldn't have to explicitly nil them out in dealloc. You'll get the default ARC behavior of nilling/releasing automatically.

Comment: I realized I could also check this with a small piece of code and it's indeed like you say, it nils them automatically.

Comment: @Patrick I wonder if you can release your test code (on Github Snippets or something).

Comment: @adib This code currently does work anymore, see [SO 9684972](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274397)

Comment: @adib Oh, I'm sorry mislinked it. It is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684972)

Comment: @Patrick Thanks. Bugs like this are kinda scary & made me hesitant to trust ARC & want to back to MRC :(

Comment: @adib As detailed in the linked question, this is issue has been fixed and works again as of Xcode 4.6 (or more likely the LLVM version it ships).

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. Putting `__attribute__((NSObject))` in a property declaration does not make the underlying instance variable ARC-managed, according to the ARC spec.

Comment: @user102008 Oh wow, you're right. I never noticed that caveat before. I went ahead and tested and it's correct, the object isn't released if you access the ivar directly, and it doesn't touch the ivar/property in dealloc.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is, do I still need to explicitly set those properties
>   to nil in my dealloc?

**Yes**, you do, with the declaration you showed.

In the [Property declarations section](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) of the ARC specification, it says:

> Applying `__attribute__((NSObject))` to a property not of retainable
>   object pointer type has the same behavior it does outside of ARC: it
>   requires the property type to be some sort of pointer and permits the
>   use of modifiers other than `assign`. These modifiers only affect the
>   synthesized getter and setter; direct accesses to the ivar (even if
>   synthesized) still have primitive semantics, and **the value in the
>   ivar will not be automatically released during deallocation**.

(emphasis on last part added by me)

In other words, applying `__attribute__((NSObject))` and `strong` on a property with Core Foundation type makes the getters and setters work correctly, but it will not make ARC manage the underlying instance variable (because the instance variable's type will still be the Core Foundation type), and thus ARC will not release the instance variable upon `dealloc` if it is non-nil. With such a property declaration, you will have to nil it in `dealloc` or cause a leak.

However, there is a way to make ARC manage the variable itself. Since the variable has a Core Foundation type, you can make it an ARC-managed type by wrapping it in a `typedef` with `__attribute__((NSObject))`.

The [Retainable object pointers section](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers) of the ARC specification says:

> There are three kinds of retainable object pointer types:
>
> - block pointers (formed by applying the caret (`^`) declarator
>     sigil to a function type)
> - Objective-C object pointers (`id`, `Class`, `NSFoo*`, etc.)
> - **typedefs marked with `__attribute__((NSObject))`**

(emphasis on last item added by me)

So if you make a typedef like this:

```
typedef __attribute__((NSObject)) CGImageRef MyImageRef;
```

and declare your property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyImageRef loupeImage;
```

the underlying variable will be managed by ARC (because the underlying variable will have the `typedef`'d type, which is an ARC-managed type) and you will not have to nil it in `dealloc`.