# Returning Objective-C object with Core Foundation attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I have a method that returns an NSArray of a custom object called "Credential" that has two properties: an NSString and a CFDataRef.

As you have noticed the object has two types of properties, a NS Objective-C property and a Core-Foundation property.

The object is initialized at every interation loop as it fills the NSArray like this:

```
cred = [[Credential alloc] init];
cred.cn = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString *)(summary)];
cred.serialNumber = CFDataCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, serialNumber);
```

When I run the analyzer I'm getting the message:

```
Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this 
execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

I'm assuming this warning happens because I'm initializing a CF object and returning from the method without releasing it, yet the new responsible for releasing the object should
be the code calling the method.

Where should I call the CFRelease of the CFDataRef property of the Credential class?

**EDIT:**

I'm using ARC so I leave to him the responsibility of releasing the NSString (cred.cn). About the CFDataRef (cred.serialNumber), though, I'm not releasing it, since I'll need it later from another class and part of the code. Then, I'm not sure how to manage it. Does ARC release it when the object "Credential" is disposed? If not, can I overwrite the dealloc method of Credential to do the CFRelease of serialNumber there?

Here's the full method that initializes and returns the NSArray of Credential objects:

```
- (NSArray *) retrieveIdentities
{
    CFArrayRef identities = NULL;
    NSMutableArray *returnIdentities = nil;
    OSStatus sanityCheck = NULL;

    const void *keys[] = {kSecClass, kSecMatchLimit, kSecReturnRef, kSecReturnData, kSecReturnAttributes};
    const void *values[] = {kSecClassIdentity, kSecMatchLimitAll, kCFBooleanTrue, kCFBooleanTrue, kCFBooleanTrue};
    CFDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, sizeof(values)/sizeof(const void *), NULL, NULL);

    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching(query, (CFTypeRef *)&identities);

    if (query)
        CFRelease(query);
    if (sanityCheck == errSecItemNotFound)
        return nil;
    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
        @throw [[KeychainException alloc] initWithName:@"KeychainException" reason:@"ERROR_LISTING_IDENTITIES" userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithLong: sanityCheck], @"osstatus", nil]];

    CFDictionaryRef result = NULL;
    CFStringRef summary = NULL;
    SecCertificateRef certificate = NULL;
    CFDataRef serialNumber = NULL;
    Credential *cred = nil;
    CFIndex resultCount = CFArrayGetCount(identities);

    returnIdentities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i<resultCount; i++)
    {
        result = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(identities,i);
        SecIdentityRef identity = (SecIdentityRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(result, kSecValueRef);

        if ((sanityCheck = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate)) != noErr)
             @throw [[KeychainException alloc] initWithName:@"KeychainException" reason:@"ERROR_EXTRACTING_CERTIFICATE" userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithLong: sanityCheck], @"osstatus", nil]];

        CFTypeRef keyClass = CFDictionaryGetValue(result, kSecAttrKeyClass);
        if ([[(__bridge id)keyClass description] isEqual:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate)])
        {
            summary = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate);
            serialNumber = CFDataCreateCopy(NULL, CFDictionaryGetValue(result, kSecAttrSerialNumber));
            cred = [[Credential alloc] init];
            cred.cn = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString *)(summary)];
            cred.serialNumber = CFDataCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, serialNumber);
            [returnIdentities addObject:cred];

            if (summary)
                CFRelease(summary);

            if (serialNumber)
                CFRelease(serialNumber);
        }
    }

    if (certificate)
        CFRelease(certificate);


    return returnIdentities;
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting (bridging) the sting but not the data?

Comment: Because I'm storing the data as a CFDataRef object since I need it that way when using it afterwards.

Comment: So you need to show how you're dealing with the ownership of both the string and the data and how you're releasing the CF objects.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more (and hopefully useful) information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line

```
cred.serialNumber = CFDataCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, serialNumber);
```

`CFDataCreateCopy` creates an object with a +1 retain count, which you're not releasing anywhere after. That's why the analyzer is warning you.

Replacing that line with the following code should fix it

```
CFDataRef sn = CFDataCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, serialNumber);
cred.serialNumber = sn;
CFRelease(sn);
```

The key is that you're messing with ownerships, therefore confusing the analyzer.

You're expected to release whatever object you created with New, Copy or Retain functions **within** the current scope, so you really shoud release the object you created with `CFDataCreateCopy`.

If then the `Credential` instance needs to retain the value you're assign to `serialNumber`, he should be responsible for that, not the caller.
In order to do so, just declare the `serialNumber` property of `Credential` as `strong` or `copy` and let ARC do its magic.

**EDIT** 
Since from the comments it appears that the `serialNumber` property has a `CFDataRef` type, you can still have to `Credential` object to retain it, by turning it in a retainable object pointer, like follows

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFDataRef serialNumber;
```

The `NSObject` attribute will make the compiler to treat it as an object, memory management wise. This is well explained in the [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers).

Comment: However, notice that serialNumber property of Credential cannot be declared strong/copy for not being of object type

Comment: You can declare it as `@property(retain) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFDataRef serialNumber;` you may want to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274397/retained-core-foundation-property

Comment: That was revealing! Didn't know that at all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If the string in created using a CF function which means you own it, you should transfer the ownership to ARC. Currently you're just bridging the reference to ARC won't take ownership.

For the data, you need to override `dealloc` and call `CFRelease` on the data.

---

The analyzer isn't perfect. Some things it finds difficult so it errs on the side of caution and tells you there might be a problem.

To be sure, particularly with leaks and memory management, you should use `Instruments` to check what's happening.

Comment: After doing what you suggested I keep getting the potential leak warning. Although it's probably because the analyzer cannot know what happens to the object after returning from the method (whether or not the dealloc it's overridden with a CFRelease of data). And as Apple documentation says: "Static analysis produces false positives. False positives are unlikely problems in source code that the analyzer identifies as problems. Source-code annotations help reduce false positives" so I guess it's probably a false positive.

Comment: Checking in instruments is the best option.

Comment: Following your advise I used instruments (after partially learning how it works) to detect leaks in my code. If I don't override the dealloc method with CFRelease it detects a leak in the line where cn.serialNumber is assigned, whereas if I override it, the leak disappears. So in short, the analyzer must be giving a false positive. If you edit your answer with the conclusions I'll mark it as correct. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks, but after reading other answers I think Gabriele's answer is more accurate since it resolves the analyzer confusion. However I'll give +1 to your answer because it is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, your creating two copies of the serial number but only releasing one.

You can convert a CF object to its corresponding NS object and take care of releasing the CF object using the macro `CFBridgingRelease`.  The release happens at the end of the statement, after ARC has retained the object if it needed to.

```
NSString *summary = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate));
NSData *serialNumber = CFBridgingRelease(CFDictionaryGetValue(result, kSecAttrSerialNumber));
cred = [[Credential alloc] init];
cred.cn = [summary copy];
cred.serialNumber = [serialNumber copy];
```

The basic rule is that you can use `CFBridgingRelease` instead of `CFRelease`.  It balances the retain from the CF Create or Copy function, and it returns an Objective-C object reference that ARC will take care of.

Comment: Sorry, but I'd like to keep serial number as a Core Foundation object to avoid conversions when accessing it.