# Right way to use __attribute__((NSObject)) with ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

**I just use CFNumber as a example，so it can be any type don't have a Fundation toll-free part!**

I just write some test code like this:

```
typedef  __attribute__((NSObject)) CFNumberRef MYNumberRef;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
    MYNumberRef ptr = NULL;
    double myDouble = 10.1;
    ptr = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
    CFIndex count = CFGetRetainCount(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is very strange that the count is 2. But if I use `CFNumberRef`, the count is 1. It seems the `arc` don't take the `CFType` name convention into account, it just `retain`s the return value.

So if I use the `__attribute__((NSObject))` to declare `CFType` property. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274397/retained-core-foundation-property) said `you shouldn't have to explicitly nil them out in dealloc.` But if I use like this:

```
   @property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFNumberRef number;
```

Then:

```
   self.number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
```

There is no memory leak if I don't release it in the `dealloc` method? Maybe I should use it like this:

```
  CFNumbeRef ref =  CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
  self.number = ref;
  CFRelease(ref);
```

Does Apple say something about this?

Comment: can't you just bridge transfer cast it to `NSNumber`?

Comment: @BryanChen，I just use CFNumber as a example，so it can be any type don't have a Fundation toll-free part!

Comment: Fine. First, retain count is useless inside `@autoreleasepool`. Second, use Instrument to test it have memory leak or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not do this.

Apple does have something to say about it in [the Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id9):

> The use of `__attribute__((NSObject))` typedefs is not recommended. If it’s absolutely necessary to use this attribute, be very explicit about using the typedef, and do not assume that it will be preserved by language features like `__typeof` and C++ template argument substitution.

`CFGetRetainCount` is [meaningless](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111073519/http://whentouseretaincount.com/). Worse than meaningless because you think it might mean something.

Comment: But if don't do this, how can I manage the CoreFundation object as a property?

Comment: Generally you make it `assign` and handle the memory management by hand in the setter (calling `CFRetain` on the new value and `CFRelease` on the old value). Obviously you shouldn't do that for something bridged like `CFNumber`. You should just use `NSNumber`. But for non-bridged CF objects, that's how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

The type attribute `__attribute__((NSObject))` does not mean that ARC will manage the memory for that type exactly the same way as if that type was an Objective-C object.

The attribute only means that in situations where the compiler automatically generates code for handling that type and the generated code is different depending on whether that type is a normal pointer or an Objective-C object pointer, the compiler should generate the code version for Objective-C objects.

This basically only influences two situations (as of today):

1. When using these pointers within blocks (`^{ }`), as objects get automatically retained when being captured by blocks and released again when the block is destroyed.
2. When assigning values to properties (`@property`) because when assigning objects to `strong` (= `retain`) properties, they get retained and the old property value gets released.

Both situations have nothing to do with ARC. Even in a non-ARC environment the compiler will generated code that works this way.

The reason why your code didn't work as expected is simply because it is wrong.

```
self.number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
```

`CFNumberCreate()` creates a new object with a retain count of (at least) 1 but this object is not managed by ARC, applying the attribute `__attribute__((NSObject))` to the type won't change that. So somewhere this create must be balanced with a release.

When you assign the value to `self.number`, it gets retained again, this time because of the `__attribute__((NSObject))` attribute, so now the retain count is (at least) 2. When your object is deallocated, `self.number` is set to `nil`, which balances the second retain but there is nothing that would balance the initial create and thus the object will leak.

Consider this code:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSNumber * number;
self.number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
```

Without ARC this code would leak as well, because again, `alloc/init` produces an object with a retain count of (at least) 1, when you assign it to `self.number`, the retain count becomes (at least) 2. Even if you do `self.number = nil;` in `dealloc`, this only balances the retain of the property, but where would the `alloc/init` get balanced?

Only with ARC this code won't leak as with ARC, the code the compiler generates looks like this:

```
NSNumber * tmp = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10];
self.number = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

And last line balances the first line, the object is still kept alive by `self.number`, unless you set `self.number = nil;` in `dealloc` which ARC will also do for you so with ARC, there is nothing else you have to do because ARC takes care of any object created with `alloc`.

That said, keep in mind that

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]
```

which is the same as `@(10)` in modern Obj-C, is in fact equal to

```
[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10] autorelease]
```

But even when you use ARC, it won't care for references created by `CFNumberCreate()`. To fix your code, it should be:

```
CFNumberRef num = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
self.number = num;
CFRelease(num);
```

Now the last line balances the first line, but the property keeps the `CFNumberRef` alive and this is automatically balanced by `dealloc` when using ARC or when not using ARC, must be balanced with a `self.number = nil;` in `dealloc`.

If you use ARC, you can also do this instead:

```
self.number = (__bridge CFNumberRef)(__bridge_transfer id)
    CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &myDouble);
```

`(__bridge_transfer id)` tells the compiler that the value returned by `CFNumberCreate()` is an Objective-C object that has a retain which needs to be balanced and ARC should take ownership of this object and take care of the balance. `(__bridge CFNumberRef)` then casts the type back to `CFNumberRef` but without transferring ownership away from ARC. Without ARC the code above leaks again, yet the compiler will warn you without ARC that bridge casts do nothing.

By the way, to transfer ownership away from ARC, the cast would be `(__bridge_retained CFNumberRef)`, in which case ARC will once retain the object for you and then give you a reference that you must release yourself to balance that retain (now you own the object reference and ARC won't manage it anymore for you).