# Can block capture a CoreFundation object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, core-foundation

In [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1) I can't find what I can do when I want to capture a **CoreFoundation** object.

But in Apple's  [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It seems the sample code use some code when dispatch object is not support ARC just like this:

```
   void average_async(int *data, size_t len, dispatch_queue_t queue, void (^block)(int))

   {

        // Retain the queue provided by the user to make

        // sure it does not disappear before the completion

        // block can be called.

        dispatch_retain(queue);


        // Do the work on the default concurrent queue and then

        // call the user-provided block with the results.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

           int avg = average(data, len);

           dispatch_async(queue, ^{ block(avg);});



           // Release the user-provided queue when done

           dispatch_release(queue);

       });
   }
```

Do I need to use `CFObject` like the `DispatchObject` before. But if I need to invoke the block many times?

Maybe I can use `__attribute__((NSObject))`, but I don't know what will happen!

Does Apple say something about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything at Apple explicitly, but I do see some [mentions in the llvm.org documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects), which I found elaborated on [in this cocoa-dev mailing list thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/307097-blocks-and-retaining-corefoundation-objects.html).

It looks like you should be okay for using `__attribute__((NSObject))`, as it's given an implicit "`__strong`" qualification (from the documentation) and in a practical sense (from the mailing list thread), the object is retained when the block is queued up and released when the block finishes.

Comment: I also have post [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090776/right-way-to-use-attribute-nsobject-with-arc)) about how to use the __attribute__((NSObject)).Seems things become very strange when use this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `dispatch_queue_t` is not a Core Foundation object.

Dispatch objects are considered Objective-C objects by the compiler (for ARC and blocks purposes) [if your deployment target is iOS 6+ / OS X 10.8+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8619055/102008).

Comment: I don't say dispatch_queue is a Core Fundation object. I just think it has to manage it's memory like a Core Fundation object before iOS6. So I wonder how to manage a Core Fundation object when it is captured by a block because I can't see anything form apple's documents.